# How to replace dictionary values which is dictionary with tuple for each dictionary in list

Tags: python, dictionary

> error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'

when i'm trying to replace dictionary value in the last line of code, but not in the loop it works (3 line of code).

```
dictionary = { "a" : "100", "b" : "200", "c" : {"a":"f","b":"4"} }
D = [dictionary for i in range(10)]
#dictionary["c"] = tuple(dictionary["c"].items()) # it works
for i in D:
    i["c"] = tuple(i["c"].items()) # does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because when you do:

```
D = [dictionary for i in range(10)]
```

You create a list with 10 references to the same object. Once the first iteration succesfully does:

```
i['c'] = tuple(i['c'].items())
```

The next one is guaranteed to fail, since it is *the same object you dealt with on the previous iteration*, so the `'c'` value is a `tuple`!

Note:

```
In [10]: dictionary = { "a" : "100", "b" : "200", "c" : {"a":"f","b":"4"} }
    ...: D = [dictionary for i in range(10)]
    ...: print([hex(id(x)) for x in D])
    ...:
['0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088', '0x105c59088']
```

Instead, do something like:

```
In [11]: dictionary = { "a" : "100", "b" : "200", "c" : {"a":"f","b":"4"} }
    ...: D = [dictionary.copy() for i in range(10)]
    ...: print([hex(id(x)) for x in D])
    ...:
['0x105c592c8', '0x105c59e48', '0x105cfd848', '0x105c9af48', '0x105d06c48', '0x105c59708', '0x105d06cc8', '0x105c59488', '0x105c59e08', '0x105c593c8']
```

And now it will work:

```
In [12]: for i in D:
    ...:     i['c'] = tuple(i['c'].items())
    ...:

In [13]: D
Out[13]:
[{'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))},
 {'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': (('b', '4'), ('a', 'f'))}]
```

Comment: Since there's another level of nesting (that doesn't have an impact for this operation evidently) it might be worth mentioning that `dict.copy` is shallow.